# Cutting of spherical mirrors

Tags: geometric-optics

suppose u have a concave mirror and a point object $O$ placed along the its principal axis

[image]

if we cut the mirror in half and displace each peice by x units above and below the prinicpal axis

[image]

where is the new principal axis and how many images will be formed???

according to me the principal axis should remain the same, however, my teacher says I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to separate the two pieces by translating them **along the circumference of the circle**, you'd be roughly correct.  But since you only translated them along the y-axis, you have to re-calculate the principal axis for each section separately.  The centers of the new circles to which each belongs are different.

To get a bit technical, the ideal reflector for optimum focus is a parabola.  We use spheres because they are much easier to fabricate and because we can make any point on the sphere (circle) the principal axis point by rotating the sphere.  For "small" curvatures the difference between the circle and the parabola shapes is very small.  But in this case you haven't rotated either section, so their principal axes are quite different so far as the object is concerned.